# Chrome Latest version (Version > 47) : Cannot access camera on non-secured pages. i.e. http page. While it works for https pages

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, webcam

I had implemented something to access camera using html5. It was working fine on FF and chrome browsers for both **http and https** pages.

But, after getting latest version of Chrome, camera is inaccessible on non-secured pages. i.e. "http". It is throwing exception as

> message: "Only secure origins are allowed (see: https://goo.gl/Y0ZkNV)."
>
> name: "PermissionDeniedError"

As per link in I got in exception shows that, Chrome is not going to allow camera access on http pages.

This code is already in production.

We cannot force customers to use https pages as it would be expensive to get SSL certificate.

Comment: same after update, may be there are some option in chrome settings, I am trying to find it

Comment: Seems like no one of WebRTC settings is related to allow access from non-secured pages. All my customers now work in FireFox. It is a pity.

Comment: What price for a SSL certificate would you regard as expensive? I bought one recently, valid for three years, for around USD15. Personally I think it is a good thing that a browser forces you to encrypt web-cam streams - they are vulnerable to interception.